# how to design a two column form using bootstrap 2.3.2 where the 2nd column takes up the rest space

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2, column-width

I would like to design a two column horizontal form using Bootstrap V2.3.2. The following is the html:

```
<div id='content' class='row-fluid'>
<div class='span12 main'>
<h2>Product Data</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAppName" class="control-label col-xs-2">Application Name&nbsp;  </label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_name" name="app_name" placeholder="Application Name">
</div>
</div>
<div style="height:10px;"></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputAppDesc" class="control-label col-xs-2">Description&nbsp;</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
<textarea class="form-control" id="app_desc" name="app_desc" rows="4" placeholder="Application Description"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

I find that the width of the input-text and textarea on the second column are smaller.  I would like to extend them to take up the rest space.  I tried to use the "input-block-level" class but the input-text and textarea will then not be on the same row as the label.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to don't use the `Bootstrap 3` class...

Try `Bootstrap 2` instead... Replace `col-xx-[1-12]` by `span[1-12]`

Your code with input in span11 :

http://www.bootply.com/119374

```
<div id="content" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 main">
        <h2>Product Data</h2>
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group row-fluid">
            <label for="inputAppName" class="control-label span2">Application Name&nbsp;  </label>
            <div class="span10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control span11" id="app_name" name="app_name" placeholder="Application Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="height:10px;">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row-fluid">
            <label for="inputAppDesc" class="control-label span2">Description&nbsp;</label>
            <div class="span10">
              <textarea class="form-control span11" id="app_desc" name="app_desc" rows="4" placeholder="Application Description"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was not aware that col-xx-[1-12] is Bootstrap3's classes.  This answer really helps.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<form>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-6">

          <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon">

              <input type="checkbox">

            </span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control">

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">

          <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon">

              <input type="radio">

            </span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control">

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

</form>
```